# does html understand condition statements

Tags: html

Does html contian condition statements
  like::::
        1.if else
        2.while
        3.for

Answer (score 7):

No, HTML is a declarative markup language, not an imperative programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few VERY basic ones - especially for checking the browser:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Comment: Those are not part of HTML, and are extremely limited even when it comes to checking the browser.

Comment: Yah, true ;-)... Guilty as charged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to look at JavaScript in order to do that. HTML is not a programming language. If it does, I wouldn't recommend neither.